# What is the proper set up for Maven to communicate with Docker daemon on Mac?

Tags: maven, docker, docker-build

I keep trying to build a Docker images of my Maven spring boot project on my Mac.

Here is my build section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
             </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>tag-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>tag</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <image>my-image</image>
        <newName>registry.example.com/my-image</newName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

When I run this command:  `mvn -X package docker:build`

I get this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.13:build (build-image) 
on project Spring-Boot-ReceiverAPI: Exception caught: 
Request error: 
POST unix://localhost:80/build?t=uptake/Spring-Boot-ReceiverAPI: 500: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my DOCKER_HOST:

```
echo $DOCKER_HOST
unix:///private/var/run/docker.sock
```

All other docker commands run fine:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                       <none>              384ed96af950        4 hours ago         640.9 MB
java                         8                   96cddf5ae9f1        10 days ago         640.9 MB
containersol/minimesos-cli   0.10.2              0f8fd0fee007        8 weeks ago         133.7 MB
```

The Docker daemon is clearly running, and the value of DOCKER_HOST appers to work fine for normal Docker command.

What can I do, to make the docker build work on Mac?

Comment: https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/218

Comment: It looks like it should work without anything if `docker-client` has been updated or `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock` which is the same as you have set. How are you setting `DOCKER_HOST` in the maven environment?

Comment: I don't know how to set up DOCKER_HOST in the Maven environment. Is it done via some keys in POM?

Comment: Docker is something different from Maven. If you need to setup docker you should try `eval $(docker-maschine default env)` afterwards a `docker ps -a` should output something usefull...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by enabling my regular user account to run docker commands without using sudo.
Here is the build section of the POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
             </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>tag-image</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>tag</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <image>api</image>
        <newName>registry.example.com/api</newName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>       
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/docker</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>Dockerfile</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
```

And here is the command, which runs fine under a regular user account:

```
mvn -X package docker:build
```

Comment: Not working for me. I am using Docker Version 2.0.0.0-mac81 (29211). $ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_172, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac". This is my pom.xml. https://pastebin.com/LiS8nvWf  and this is the output https://pastebin.com/8QKieuHw

Comment: Solved! The container name must be in  lowercase.